# Bootstrap Modal Form doesn't insert data in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the bootstrap modal, it doesn't insert data in MySQL even though i have a similar modal in the same page that updates the data.. The data is represented in tables with delete and update buttons for each row... Which both work well in the same page.. I am not using Ajax and i was hoping this would work without using any other technologies.. it's kinda odd as the update query uses the same technique and still works regardless

```
            <?php
            require_once "../db.php";
            session_start();
            if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
                header('location:login.php');
            }
            function redirect($url)
        {
            if (!headers_sent())
            {    
                header('Location: '.$url);
                exit;
                }
            else
                {  
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
                echo '</script>';
                echo '<noscript>';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
                echo '</noscript>'; exit;
            }
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script srC="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <style>
            .nav-link{
                font-size:18px;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['confirmadd'])){
                    $code = $_POST['voyage'];
                    $newrow0 = $_POST['depart'];
                    $newrow1 = $_POST['villedep'];
                    $newrow2 = $_POST['arrivee'];
                    $newrow3 = $_POST['villearr'];
                    $newrow4 = $_POST['price'];
                    $addTrip = mysqli_query($sql,"INSERT INTO voyage VALUES('$code','$newrow0','$newrow1',$newrow2','$newrow3','$newrow4');");
                    if($addTrip){
                    redirect('dashboard.php');
                    }else{
                        echo "error";
                    }
                } 
    ?>
        <div class="container-fluid bg-info sticky-top">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="col-6 offset-1">
                <h2 class="display-4 text-white">AnouBus</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
            <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
                <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <h1 class="text-center">Your Trips</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mx-2" style="float:right;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addmodal">Add Trip</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="addmodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"><h2 class="text-center">Update Trip</h2></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="voyage" class="form-control" placeholder="Trip Code">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="depart" class="form-control" placeholder="Departure Time" ?>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="villedep" class="form-control" placeholder="Departure City">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="arrivee" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrival Time">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="villearr" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrival City">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" name="confirmadd" value="confirm">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where's the code that puts data in your database?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i'm sorry i've just added it now

Comment: It all looks fine to me. Since you don't report to see the "error" message the logical assumption is that the query is never executed. Since you're not showing us your complete source code, it could be something as simple as two `if(isset($_POST['confirmadd']))` lines. I can't tell. What I always do in these cases is put several echo's in the code in several places to see what code is being executed. In the end the query should get executed, if it doesn't nothing will be inserted.